# MacOS: Package compilation fails in renv project, but succeeds outside renv

Tags: r, renv

I've cloned an Rproject that uses `renv` and it is failing to restore a package (`cluster`) due to not locating gcc and gfortran.

I've done diagnostics and have found that in Rstudio with the renv project loaded, `Sys.which("gfortran")` gives different results than outside of an renv project.

Outside renv: `"/opt/homebrew/bin/gfortran"` (which is correct, and matches the location when I check `which gfortran` in terminal.
Inside the renv project, I get an empty string: `""`

How is `renv` able to affect my system paths like this? Per the help for `Sys.which()`, "This is an interface to the system command `which`". Or where in the Rproj/renv settings are paths set that overrule system paths?